# Apex - Schedulable class cannot execute Batchable class

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm having trouble with a Batchable and Schedulable Apex class that I've written. Basically, the Schedulable class will not call the Batchable class to run the code in there. Here's what I've written:

**rw_BillingInvoiceCreationSchedulable.apxc**

```
global class rw_BillingInvoiceCreationSchedulable implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        System.debug('Batchable queued for execution');
        rw_BillingInvoiceCreationBatchable b = new rw_BillingInvoiceCreationBatchable();
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(b);
        System.debug('Batchable was executed: ' + JSON.serialize(b));
    }
}
```

**rw_BillingInvoiceCreationBatchable.apxc**

```
global class rw_BillingInvoiceCreationBatchable implements Database.batchable<SObject> {

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        System.debug('Batch Apex called');
        Date closingTime = date.today().toStartOfWeek();
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, Name, rw_Batch_Sequence__c, rw_End_Date__c, rw_Closed__c, rw_Customer__c, rw_Start_Date__c, rw_Warehouse__c
                                        FROM rw_Invoice_Batch__c
                                        WHERE rw_Closed__c = FALSE]);
        // AND rw_End_Date__c < :closingTime
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<rw_Invoice_Batch__c> scope) {
        System.debug('Invoices about to be updated');
        List<rw_Invoice_Batch__c> invoices = new List<rw_Invoice_Batch__c>();
        List<Account> activeCustomers = [SELECT Id, Name
                                         FROM Account
                                         WHERE Inventory_Management__c = TRUE OR Order_Management__c = TRUE];
        for(rw_Invoice_Batch__c i : scope) {
            i.rw_Closed__c = TRUE;
            invoices.add(i);
            rw_InvoiceGenerator.generateInvoice(i);
        }
        update invoices;
        System.debug('Invoices updated to closed');
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }
}
```

I can confirm that the Batchable class is working, as far as the test class goes. I ran its test class and it always returns success, but for the Schedulable class, the test class or actually running it will always yield the same result: nothing. I'm not sure if there's any restrictions in place or tweaks I can make that will allow the code to run, but I'm open to any suggestions or ideas as to what it is.

Comment: How are you scheduling this?

Comment: Or is this an issue only within test context?